# Apache websocket works with ProxyPass but not RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, websocket, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-wstunnel

I'm trying to enable websockets on an AWS ElasticBeanstalk Tomcat 8.5 web app. I have a custom apache config (abbreviated):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on

# send websocket requests to tomcat with the websocket protocol
RewriteCond ${HTTP:Connection}  "Upgrade" [NC]
RewriteCond ${HTTP:Upgrade}     "websocket" [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) "ws://localhost:8080/$1" [P,L]

# send all other requests to tomcat
ProxyPass           /   http://localhost:8080/  retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8080/
```

In the web app, when I try to connect the client websocket to the server endpoint, I get this error:

> websocket.js:372 WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/ws/sales' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I verified in Chrome's developer tools that the Connection and Upgrade headers sent in the request to the above endpoint are correct. (Obviously I'm really connecting to my website, not example.com)

**When I change the apache config to use ProxyPass instead of RewriteRule, it works perfectly!** I don't want to do it this way because I don't want to proxy to ws simply based on the URI. I want to check the headers like you're supposed to!

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on

# send websocket requests to tomcat with the websocket protocol
ProxyPass           /ws/    ws://localhost:8080/ws/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    /ws/    ws://localhost:8080/ws/

# send all other requests to tomcat
ProxyPass           /   http://localhost:8080/  retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the solution to this simply by trial and error, which is to remove the `L` (last) flag from the `RewriteRule`. What I don't understand still is why that fixes it. I figured it would be good to post this answer anyway.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on

# send websocket requests to tomcat with the websocket protocol
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}     "websocket" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection}  "Upgrade" [NC]
RewriteRule .* "ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI}" [P]

# send all other requests to tomcat
ProxyPass           /   http://localhost:8080/  retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8080/
```